# E: Unable to locate package libmpg123-dev

Tags: raspberry-pi, adafruit

I am trying to follow this article  to get a USB sound driver set up for my rapsberry pi 3 with raspbian OS:

https://learn.adafruit.com/usb-audio-cards-with-a-raspberry-pi/testing-audio

I am able to test it with SonicPi and the speaker test command for the command line but I am having trouble downloading mpg123.  The error message is as follows:

---

pi@JoeLyons_raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libmpg123-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

### E: Unable to locate package libmpg123-dev

I tried googling this but it seems oddly specific to me so I'm afraid I've messed around with the wrong config files or something at some point.  Any help on how to troubleshoot why this won't download would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

P.S. I've also tried this variation:

pi@JoeLyons_raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mpg123
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mpg123 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mpg123' has no installation candidate

Comment: How you updated the package lists?  `apt-get update`

Comment: Yes, and I also did an upgrade and reboot

Answer (score 0):

remove the libmpg123-* first
will remove mplayer ardour and any dependencies related

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libmpg123-0
sudo apt-get install  libmpg123-dev
```